# Tabular String data convert to python data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a string like this

```
"""PID TTY          TIME CMD
      1 ?        00:00:01 systemd
      2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
      3 ?        00:00:00 rcu_gp
      4 ?        00:00:00 rcu_par_gp"""
```

now I want the data to be like so that i can access it like `data["PID"]` will give me `1,2,3,4 and so for other headers.`

I have used `pandas` and `StringIO` to convert it to a `dataframe` but the output of `df.columns` give `['PID TTY', 'TIME CMD']` which is not something i want.

It will be better if the logic is python related and not with pandas

Comment: no, it was a mistake. somehow removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sep="\s+"` for separator by whitespace:

```
from io import StringIO

temp="""PID TTY          TIME CMD
      1 ?        00:00:01 systemd
      2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
      3 ?        00:00:00 rcu_gp
      4 ?        00:00:00 rcu_par_gp"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="\s+")
   
print (df)
   PID TTY      TIME         CMD
0    1   ?  00:00:01     systemd
1    2   ?  00:00:00    kthreadd
2    3   ?  00:00:00      rcu_gp
3    4   ?  00:00:00  rcu_par_gp
```

---

```
print (df.columns)
Index(['PID', 'TTY', 'TIME', 'CMD'], dtype='object')
```